# CMake VS2017 C++ - cannot open file opencv_world.lib

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, cmake

I'm currently working on a project and I want to add OpenCV.
I downloaded the pre-built library of opencv 3.3.1 and the latest version of cmake. 
Futhermore I use Visual Studios 2017 on a Windows x64 OS in x64 debug mode.

CMake can build everything without any errors.
However, when I want to build my project in VS or debug,
I get a fatal link error:

> fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\OpenCV 3.3.1\opencv\build\lib\Debug\opencv_world331d.lib'

So I checked the directory for the lib file.
But neither the directory nor the lib file exists.

I attach below my CMakeLists.txt:

```
SET( CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}" )
FIND_PACKAGE( KinectSDK2 REQUIRED )
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${KinectSDK2_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
LINK_DIRECTORIES( ${KinectSDK2_LIBRARY_DIRS} ) 
SET( CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}" )
FIND_PACKAGE( PCL 1.8.1 REQUIRED )
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
LINK_DIRECTORIES( ${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS} )
FIND_PACKAGE( OpenCV REQUIRED )
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
LINK_DIRECTORIES( ${OpenCV_LIBRARY_DIRS} )
MESSAGE(STATUS "OpenCV library status:")
MESSAGE(STATUS "    version: ${OpenCV_VERSION}")
MESSAGE(STATUS "    libraries: ${OpenCV_LIBS}")
MESSAGE(STATUS "    include path: ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS)
FILE( GLOB DesiredView_SRC
    "*.h"
    "*.cpp"
)
ADD_EXECUTABLE( DesiredView ${DesiredView_SRC} )

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( DesiredView ${PCL_LIBRARIES} ${KinectSDK2_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

I just started working with CMake 2 days ago.
So I'm pretty new with this.

I'm really thankful for any help.

Florian

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I see you insert `message()` calls into your code. Their output could be helpfull - add it to the question post. `I downloaded the pre-built library of opencv 3.3.1` - Where (in which directory) do you place opencv library?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer. I have to post it here however.
Here ist the message() code.

> OpenCV library status:
>       version: 3.3.1
>       libraries: opencv_calib3d;opencv_core;opencv_cudaarithm;opencv_cudabgsegm;opencv_cudacodec;opencv_cudafeatures2d;opencv_cudafilters;opencv_cudaimgproc;opencv_cudaobjdetect;opencv_cudaoptflow;opencv_cudastereo;opencv_cudawarping;opencv_dnn;opencv_features2d;opencv_flann;opencv_highgui;opencv_imgcodecs;opencv_imgproc;opencv_ml;opencv_objdetect;opencv_photo;opencv_shape;opencv_stitching;opencv_superres;opencv_video;opencv_videoio;opencv_videostab;opencv_world
>       include path: C:/OpenCV 3.3.1/opencv/build;C:/OpenCV 3.3.1/opencv/sources/include;C:/OpenCV 3.3.1/opencv/sources/include/opencv;C:/OpenCV 3.3.1/opencv/sources/modules/core/include;C:/OpenCV 3.3.1/opencv/sources/modules/cudaarithm/include;C:/OpenCV 3.3.1/opencv/sources/modules/flann/include;C:/OpenCV 3.3.1/opencv/sources/modules/imgproc/include;C:/OpenCV 3.3.1/opencv/sources/modules/ml/include;C:/OpenCV 3.3.1/opencv/sources/modules/objdetect/include;C:/OpenCV 3.3.1/opencv/sources/modules/video/include;C:/OpenCV 3.3.1/opencv/sources/modules/cudabgsegm/include;C:/OpenCV 3.3.1/opencv/sources/modules/cudafilters/include;C:/OpenCV 3.3.1/opencv/sources/modules/cudaimgproc/include;C:/OpenCV 3.3.1/opencv/sources/modules/cudawarping/include;C:/OpenCV 3.3.1/opencv/sources/modules/dnn/include;C:/OpenCV 3.3.1/opencv/sources/modules/imgcodecs/include;C:/OpenCV 3.3.1/opencv/sources/modules/photo/include;C:/OpenCV 3.3.1/opencv/sources/modules/shape/include;C:/OpenCV 3.3.1/opencv/sources/modules/videoio/include;C:/OpenCV 3.3.1/opencv/sources/modules/cudacodec/include;C:/OpenCV 3.3.1/opencv/sources/modules/cudaobjdetect/include;C:/OpenCV 3.3.1/opencv/sources/modules/cudaoptflow/include;C:/OpenCV 3.3.1/opencv/sources/modules/highgui/include;C:/OpenCV 3.3.1/opencv/sources/modules/superres/include;C:/OpenCV 3.3.1/opencv/sources/modules/features2d/include;C:/OpenCV 3.3.1/opencv/sources/modules/calib3d/include;C:/OpenCV 3.3.1/opencv/sources/modules/cudafeatures2d/include;C:/OpenCV 3.3.1/opencv/sources/modules/cudastereo/include;C:/OpenCV 3.3.1/opencv/sources/modules/stitching/include;C:/OpenCV 3.3.1/opencv/sources/modules/videostab/include;C:/OpenCV 3.3.1/opencv/sources/modules/world/include;C:/OpenCV 3.3.1/opencv/sources/modules/ts/include

My build and source Folder are situated here:

> C:\OpenCV 3.3.1\opencv

Thanks:)

Comment: I built the OpenCV-build folder with CMake again and deleted the originally downloaded build folder, because CMake couldn't find the opencv-config.cmake file. After I rebuild it it could find the cmake file however now it doesn't find the lib file as I have mentioned already. Does it have to do something with this?

Comment: The weird thing is that I can already include opencv header files and use the library. Just when I want to debug it fails.

Comment: did you compile the OpenCV in debug mode and release mode? maybe you only compiled it in release mode..

Comment: No I compile it only in debug x64 mode.

Comment: did you install it? I mean, when you compile it you need to "build" ALL_BUILD project and then "build" the INSTALL project. It will copy the libs where you specify it in the CMake configuration. Then you have to make sure the folder exists and link your app to this folder/libs

Comment: I did now. It worked. Thank you so much. I had no idea that I have to compile the cmake compiled project with Visual Studios. I suppose that when I compile with Visual Studio it creates the lib files and the dll file. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, but it creates them first in the build folder (or the one you say in the cmake to put the binaries) and then with the INSTALL one it will copy them to the final place that YOU decide (it is one of the variables in cmake).